# How to display version number a certain way

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is display my version number, but I want to display it like:

`1.2.1`

But it displays `1.2.1.0`. I don't want the fourth digit to show at all and I'm not sure how to do this.

This is what I have tried:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
labelControl5.Text = String.Format("Project Sachiko {0}", version);
```

Comment: Please, consider marking my answer as an answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `version.ToString(3)` to display only `Major.Minor.Build` version without `Revision`. For more information on formatting versions, see [MSDN: Version.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3):

There´s an overload for [`Version.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Version_ToString_System_Int32_) that accepts an int as parameter in order to print only the first three parts for example:

```
labelControl5.Text = String.Format("Project Sachiko {0}", version.ToString(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
return $"{version.Major}.{version.Minor}.{version.Build}";
```